# Target Editor not showing up in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, target, rcp

I want to run my rcp targets but I am not able to find out the target editor so that I could update features and set those as target platforms.

Let me know if I am missing some data for this question. My major concern is to see my targets in the Target Editor of Eclipse.

I installed Eclipse Kepler and I am able to see the target editor but not in Eclipse Oxygen which I am currently using.

EDIT:
I tried installing PDE for Eclipse Oxygen but its throwing me the following error:

[image]
[image: Error while installing PDE]

Comment: If you mean Target Platform xxx.target files there is no change between Kepler and Oxygen. Do you actually have Eclipse PDE installed - not all Eclipse downloads contain it. Also note that Eclipse Oxygen is 4 releases out of date.

Comment: Hi @greg-449, PDE was not installed but when I tried installing it it threw me error. Edited the question and I attached the error window as a screenshot. Please have a look!

Comment: The actual problem in that error log is off the bottom of the screen. Please don't post screen shots of text. Post the full error as plain text.